# Get all objects that don't have a specific has_many :through-related object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the following association:

```
Gemfile has_many Gems, through Dependencies
```

If I want to get all `Gemfile`s that have a specific `Gem`, I would do:

```
Gemfile.joins(dependencies: :gem).where(gems: { name: 'rails' })
```

But I can't seem to get it right to find all `Gemfile`s that **do not** have a specific `Gem`. I tried:

```
Gemfile.joins(dependencies: :gem).where.not(gems: { name: 'rails' })
```

but this obviously doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: I am using 5.0.0.beta.2 right now, but I guess any solution for it would work for >4.2 also.

Comment: Your current query should work for rails > 4.0. Can you post the SQL generated?

Comment: Also try with `Gemfile.joins(:gems).where.not(gems: { name: 'rails' })`

Comment: It works, but i don't get what I expect. Since it does an `INNER JOIN` and there are multiple `Gem`s for each `Gemfile`, a `Gemfile` having `rails` will be selected even though I don't want, since the query matches the other `Gem`s associated with this `Gemfile`...

Comment: Ok. Try `inlcudes` instead of `joins`.

Comment: That's the same, it differs only on how the join is built, which in this case yields the same results since I don't have `NULL` on the right side.